# Weird result proving : $1+2+3+...+n<\frac{(2n+1)²}{8} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

> $$1+2+3+...+n<\frac{(2n+1)²}{8} $$

So, I'm going through Apostol's Calculus, and solving this:

[image]

I want to prove the aforementioned inequality, and proceed like this :

- $A(1) = 1 < \frac{9}{8}$

  $A(2) = 1+2=3 < \frac{25}{8}$

$...$

- $A(k)=1+2+3+...+k<\frac{(2k+1)²}{8} | k≥1 $
- $A(k+1)=1+2+3+...+k+(k+1)<\color{red}{\frac{(2(k+1)+1)²}{8}} $
- $1+2+3+...+k+(k+1)<\color{red}{\frac{(2k+1)²}{8}+(k+1)} $

Now, following the way how Apostol proceeded from this point in other proofs like this one in the book, I have to prove:

$\frac{(2k+1)²}{8}+(k+1)<\frac{(2(k+1)+1)²}{8}$

But

- $\frac{(2k+1)²}{8}+(k+1)=\frac{4k²+12k+9}{8}$
- $\frac{(2(k+1)+1)²}{8}=\frac{4k²+12k+9}{8}$

So $\color{blue}{\frac{(2k+1)²}{8}+(k+1)<\frac{(2(k+1)+1)²}{8}}$ is false, but according to this other proof in the book

[image]
[image]

$\color{blue}{\frac{(2k+1)²}{8}+(k+1)<\frac{(2(k+1)+1)²}{8}}$ should be true, for the inequality to hold, but the result I'm getting tells me

> $$1+2+3+...+n=\frac{(2n+1)²}{8} $$

which seems to be false according to

> $A(1) = 1 < \frac{9}{8}$
>
> $A(2) = 1+2=3 < \frac{25}{8}$

and

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost done. Note that you should show that
$$1+2+3+\dots+k+(k+1)<\frac{(2k+1)^2}{8}+(k+1)\color{red}{\leq }\frac{(2(k+1)+1)^2}{8}.$$
which implies that
$$1+2+3+\dots+k+(k+1)< \frac{(2(k+1)+1)^2}{8}.$$
So showing that
$$\frac{(2k+1)^2}{8}+(k+1)=\frac{(2(k+1)+1)^2}{8}$$
concludes the proof.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\frac{(2(k+1)+1)^2}{8}$, and not $\frac{(2k+1)^2}{8}$.

Comment: Thanks!! I corrected the typo.

Comment: So, what it seems is that he actual inequality to be proven is 
 $1+2+3+...+n≤\frac{(2n+1)²}{8} $
And not
 $1+2+3+...+n<\frac{(2n+1)²}{8} $
?

Comment: or, maybe I'm not understanding properly, why it should be proven that 

$1+2+3+\dots+k+(k+1)<\frac{(2k+1)^2}{8}+(k+1)\color{red}{\leq }\frac{(2(k+1)+1)^2}{8}.$

instead of
$1+2+3+\dots+k+(k+1)<\frac{(2k+1)^2}{8}+(k+1)\color{red}{< }\frac{(2(k+1)+1)^2}{8}.$

Comment: Do you agree that $A<B\leq C$ implies $A<C$?